# Проблема с ini.WriteString

Tags: delphi

```
 p := 0;
 k := 0;
 ini.ReadInteger('mon', '10', p); // возвращает p = 1000
 k := strtoint(edit11.Text); // edit11.Text = 12
 p := p + k;
 ini.WriteString('mon', '10', inttostr(p)); //по идее записаться должно 1012
```

Проблема в том, что запись в ини-файл производится без сложения переменных, то есть 1000.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

**Добавлено.**

```
procedure tform1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
ini := TIniFile.Create('./set.ini')
// ini.WriteString('mon', '10', '7531'); работает отлично, но после 
//этого значение не изменяется при новом вводе
end;
procedure tform1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var p,k:i integer;
begin
p := 0;
k := 0;
ini.ReadInteger('mon', '10', p);
k := strtoint(edit11.Text);
p:= p + k;
ini.WriteString('mon', '10', inttostr(p));
end;
procedure tform1.FormClose(Sender: TObject);
begin
ini.Free;
end.
```

В общем такой код.

**Добавлено.**

Попробовал я Ваш способ, вот что получилось:

```
procedure TForm2.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var po, ki, toc: integer;
begin
    if edit6.Text <> '' then
    begin
        po := 0;
        ki := 0;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '5000', po);
        ini.Free;
        ki := strtoint(edit6.Text);
        toc := po + ki;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.WriteString('Купюры', '5000', inttostr(toc));
        ini.Free
    end else
    begin
        MessageDlg('Сначала введите количество купюр.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        edit6.Clear;
        edit6.SetFocus;
    end;
    if edit7.Text <> '' then
    begin
        po := 0;
        ki := 0;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '1000', po);
        ini.Free;
        ki := strtoint(edit7.Text);
        toc := po + ki;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.WriteString('Купюры', '1000', inttostr(toc));
        ini.Free
    end else
    begin
        MessageDlg('Сначала введите количество купюр.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        edit7.Clear;
        edit7.SetFocus;
    end;
    if edit8.Text <> '' then
    begin
        po := 0;
        ki := 0;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '500', po);
        ini.Free;
        ki := strtoint(edit8.Text);
        toc := p + k;//разобрался, надо было изменить переменные на po и ki
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.WriteString('Купюры', '500', inttostr(toc));
        ini.Free
    end else
    begin
        MessageDlg('Сначала введите количество купюр.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        edit8.Clear;
        edit8.SetFocus;
    end;
    if edit9.Text <> '' then
    begin
        po := 0;
        ki := 0;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '100', po);
        ini.Free;
        ki := strtoint(edit9.Text);
        toc := po + ki;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.WriteString('Купюры', '100', inttostr(toc));
        ini.Free
    end else
    begin
        MessageDlg('Сначала введите количество купюр.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        edit9.Clear;
        edit9.SetFocus;
    end;
    if edit10.Text <> '' then
    begin
        po := 0;
        ki := 0;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '50', po);
        ini.Free;
        ki := strtoint(edit10.Text);
        toc := po + ki;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.WriteString('Купюры', '50', inttostr(toc));
        ini.Free
    end else
    begin
        MessageDlg('Сначала введите количество купюр.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        edit10.Clear;
        edit10.SetFocus;
    end;
    if edit11.Text <> '' then
    begin
        po := 0;
        ki := 0;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.ReadInteger('Купюры', '10', po);
        ini.Free;
        ki := strtoint(edit11.Text);
        toc := po + ki;
        ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
        ini.WriteString('Купюры', '10', inttostr(toc));
        ini.Free
    end else
    begin
        MessageDlg('Сначала введите количество купюр.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
        edit11.Clear;
        edit11.SetFocus;
    end;
    ini := TIniFile.Create('./settings.ini');
    label18.Caption := '5000 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '5000', '') + ' шт.';
    label19.Caption := '1000 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '1000', '') + ' шт.';
    label20.Caption := '500 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '500', '') + ' шт.';
    label21.Caption := '100 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '100', '') + ' шт.';
    label22.Caption := '50 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '50', '') + ' шт.';
    label23.Caption := '10 = ' + ini.ReadString('Купюры', '10', '') + ' шт.';
    ini.Free;
end;
```

собственно так ничего и не вышло. мало того, что проблема осталась (добавляет не сумму, а только введенное в edit значение), так еще и добавилась одна - сколько бы не ввел в edit8, все равно в файле 500=0

Я учусь, так что не судите строго мой код.

жду помощи! :)

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что новое значение записывается вообще, а не остаётся то же, что и было сначала? Вы целиком код покажите, пожалуйста, где у вас там `ini.Free` происходит или ещё что? Работает ли то же самое если после `ini.Create` не делать `ReadInteger`, а сразу `WriteString` с каким-нибудь специальным числом, типа `7531`?

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: @Владимир Archi Используйте правильное форматирование кода: четыре пробела (табуляция) перед каждой строкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
ini.ReadInteger('mon', '10', p);
```

на

```
p:= ini.ReadInteger('mon', '10', p);
```

у вас же значение считывается, но не присваивается в `p`, несмотря на комментарий `//возвращает p = 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас Create, WriteString и Free все в разных методах. Надеюсь, вы их правильно вызываете... Но в общем подозреваю, что стоит попробовать при клике делать всё сразу, переинициализируя файл перед записью:

```
...
ini.Create
ini.ReadInteger
ini.Free
...
ini.Create
ini.WriteString
ini.Free
...
```

Если и тут не получится - попробовать записать в другую строку (скажем, mooon) и ещё - проверить что k не равно нулю после преобразования... Хотя думаю вы уже проверили.

Comment: Создание, чтение и освобождение объекта не обязаны располагаться в одном методе. А создавать/освобождать его при каждом обращении к ini-файлу и вовсе расточительно.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код будет приводить к исключению если вы попытаетесь закрыть программу не нажав кноку.
Так как создатете вы по нажатию кнопки а очищаете при выходе.

тут два решения или free делать в onClick
или create делать в OnCreate

Еще одно изварщение это параметр типа Integer хранить как String
Вы параметр читаете как Integer а пишите как String

вы или читайте его как String и пишите его WriteString
или читайте его как Integer и пишите его WriteInteger

Comment: Ну, хранятся-то они там в любом случае в виде строк. Но того, кто это будет читать, конечно не обрадует )

Comment: Я не пользовался INI давно, но по моему при создании там тип присваеваеться, и пишеться после фри.
Так что уже если страдать таким извращением, то создали прочитали как **число** закрыли сделали что нужно создали записали как **строку** закрыли.